# Declaration of User::save() should be compatible with ...\Model::save(array $options = Array)

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I am new to Laravel, coming from Codeigniter.

I am trying to load the `save()` function in the `Users` model to eventually insert the post data into the `users` table.

But I get the error

```
Declaration of User::save() should be compatible with …\Model::save(array $options = Array)
```

The form is submitted to this function in my controller.

```
public function createUser () {
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' =>Input::get('password')
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:5|max:25'
        )
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        echo 'fail';
    } else {
        $hashPass = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        //  input new row
        $user = new User(Input::except('Submit'));
        $user::save();
    }

}
```

My users model is the standard model that comes with Laravel with the lines below added. (I was just trying to make it print something.)

```
protected $fillable = array('email');

public function save ($user) 
{
    print_r($user);
}
```

I am not sure if I'm using the models correctly but nothing I've found so far has helped.

Comment: You are trying to override the Eloquent save() function, **bad idea**. Remove it from that model and look at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: Also, echo is mostly not used in Laravel. In function, return is used.

Comment: What @delmadord said - If you need to do any processing that should occur on `save`, use [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events).

Comment: Also, instead of using `echo` or `print_r` for debugging, I like to use the [raveren/kint](https://packagist.org/packages/raveren/kint) package. It formats things very nicely and allows you to browse through properties & methods in your browser.

Comment: Ok everyone. Thanks for the responses. Unfortunately I posted this on my lunch break and can't check if that works for the next couple hours.

Comment: Also should change `$user::save();` to `$user->save();`

Answer (score 4):

If you replace a function of a class, you have to define it the same way it was defined in the class.

So you need to declare the save function in this way:

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    // your before save code here

    if(parent::save($options)) {
      // your after save code here
    }
    // return boolean here
}
```

Comment: Yes. Reason: If you replace a function of a class, you have to define it the same way it was defined in the class.